# Initial fetch for nsfetchedresultscontroller returns 0 objects, subsequent fetches OK

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My initial fetch for my NSFetchedResultsController returns O objects. Most of the time (I'd say 9 times out of 10). It's not a bug that's always reproducible.

Sometimes my requirements for the table change, and my predicate changes. In that case, I delete the cache and set my FetchedResultsController to nil before I recreate it. On these subsequent fetches, it always returns the correct objects.

The fetch in question grabs objects from an entity where a relationship is involved.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"FacebookPost"];
fetch.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"postedBy.facebookID == %@", self.user.facebookID];
```

where I have two entities, |User| and |FacebookPost|
User has a one-to-many relationship with FacebookPost called facebookPosts
FacebookPost has a many-to-one relationship to User called postedBy
User has a facebookID that I'm using in the predicate (see above)

I've tried delaying the fetch in case the database wasn't ready, to no avail.

Can anyone think of why this isn't (most of the time) fetching correctly on the initial fetch?

UPDATE:

If I turn on sql debugging in Xcode, it arbitrarily uses a different SQL statement on times when it works and doesn't:

**Worked:**

2013-03-27 06:41:58.420 App[5995:907] CoreData: sql: SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT t0.Z_PK) FROM ZFACEBOOKPOST t0 WHERE  t0.ZPOSTEDBY = ?

2013-03-27 06:41:58.432 App[5995:907] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZMESSAGE, t0.ZSTATUSID, t0.ZTIME, t0.ZPOSTEDBY FROM ZFACEBOOKPOST t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)  ORDER BY t0.ZTIME DESC LIMIT 20

**Didn't work:**

2013-03-27 06:24:06.638 App[66275:c07] CoreData: sql: SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT t0.Z_PK) FROM ZFACEBOOKPOST t0 JOIN ZUSER t1 ON t0.ZPOSTEDBY = t1.Z_PK WHERE  t1.ZFACEBOOKID = ?

2013-03-27 06:24:06.641 App[66275:c07] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZMESSAGE, t0.ZSTATUSID, t0.ZTIME, t0.ZPOSTEDBY FROM ZFACEBOOKPOST t0 JOIN ZUSER t1 ON t0.ZPOSTEDBY = t1.Z_PK WHERE  t1.ZFACEBOOKID = ? ORDER BY t0.ZTIME DESC

So it makes me think it has to do with the way core data decides to execute the fetch in SQL.

Comment: I'm not sure but based on the description I'd try turning off caching to see if it made any difference. I'm wondering if the key is that subsequent fetches happen after clearing the cache-- so, experimentally, see if using no cache fixes things.

Comment: I just tried that and it worked the first two launches of the app, then started returning 0 objects again.

Comment: Are you referencing the fetched results controller correctly in your table view `datasource` methods?

Comment: Yes, I am referencing the frc correctly. And this is an issue with the fetch request returning 0 objects - before the table view comes into play. If I execute my own, separate fetch, I still get the same (0) results sporadically on first fetch. I think it has something to do with fetching on a relationship?